# Series convergence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2^{(-1)^nn}} $

Tags: calculus

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+2^{(-1)^nn}} $$

How can I show whether this series converges or not

Comment: Hint: In order for a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ to converge, a necessary condition is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$.

Comment: Consider when $n$ is odd. You have a subseries where $2^{-n} \to 0$ implies you are adding near to $1$ every odd term. Show that for all of those terms, the sequence is greater than $\dfrac{1}{n}$, which you know diverges. Then use the Comparison test.

Comment: @achillehui Can we see check the Absolute convergence of this serie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n=\frac{1}{1+2^{(-1)^nn}}.$ Then $a_n=\frac{1}{1+2^{-n}}$ if $n$ is odd.
Therfore $(a_n)$ contains a subsequence , which   converges to $1$.

This shows that $(a_n)$ does not converge to $0$.